# Copy/Pasting graph

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

I came here because i have this problem that is driving me nuts. I can't find nothing similar on the internet (maybe because it's kind of hard to explain without images).

Here's the problem:
- I want to use a macro to copy a box plot graph from a sheet and paste it on another sheet using the following code (since i am running a for cycle i use some variables on the coordinates in the sheet):

```
Sheets(s + 4).Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Gráfico 9").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
Sheets("Print").Select
ActiveSheet.Cells(l + 22, 3).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

- Using this code i obtain something like this:
  https://pasteboard.co/JcIPqxR.png
  As you can see, the "Cmin" value is in a very strange format (,320.0) as the value in the table is just 0,32.
- Once i Copy and Paste it manually, even after using the macro, i obtain the 0,32 on the graph.
- This also works if i just right-click then "select data" and just cancel without any modification.
- If I change the decimal cases shown on the table it comes back to normal too, but it would be too much efford to change 4800 tables.

I even tried to create an additional macro that would change de decimal cases of certain table values but it makes things worse, completely altering the values shown in the chart.
The methods said earlier still correct the issue in this case.

Do you have any suggetions for solving this problem?

My excel version is 2013 running on a windows 10.

Thank you for your attention in advance.

Diogo,

Comment: Did you mean to include an image?  If so, it is currently missing.  If not, please consider doing so - it may help us to understand your issue better

Comment: Hello Chronocidal, 
Thank you for your concern, but i don't understand the question.
My objective is to build a compact report base on information within separate sheets. Along with other relevant information i need to copy graphs/charts and i do so as they are, not as an image. Regards

Comment: I meant, did you mean to include an image in the *question*:  You have *"[…]i obtain something like this: **[Graph Image][1]** As you can see,[…]"*, which suggests that there was supposed to be an image of your graph there, for us to see.  You may need to [edit] your question, because we currently *can't* see the "strange format" of the "Cmin" value

Comment: Hello Chronocidal,

I see what you meant, it was supposed to be a link in that picture.
Can you check if you can open the link now?